# Got Connect Failed error when request to tf serving server,and it's all good in windows

Tags: grpc, tensorflow-serving

I make a server and request successfully in windows,then I put them to the linux which is the develop machine of company.

And I Got Connect Failed error when I run the clien.py. I have changed the host IP to `localhost,0.0.0.0,127.0.0.1` and the IP of develop machine,but it doesn't work.

And I tried the `docker inspect` command,but the `IPAddress` is empty like `""`.
And I changed the port to 8500,8501,4321 and still got the error.

I tried make proxy to the company,the request returns a `Name resolution failure` error.So I think maybe the cause is the net of company?

Any answer would be very appreciate!

The Error Message:

```
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "Connect Failed"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1551677753.381330483","description":"Failed to create subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":2721,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1551677753.381328206","description":"Pick Cancelled","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":241,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1551677753.381303114","description":"Connect Failed","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.cc","file_line":689,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1551677753.381278484","description":"Failed to connect to remote host: OS Error","errno":111,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_posix.cc","file_line":205,"os_error":"Connection refused","syscall":"connect","target_address":"ipv4:0.0.0.0:8501"}]}]}]}"
```

Comment: Where did you run your client.py? Have you changed host and port in client.py to your develop machine? Are you sure that you can make some request successfully, no matter grpc or http, from your local windows to develop machine? Maybe check the net first. Post your client.py and the way you started tf-serving seems better.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on how you are running the server and the client (i.e. whether you are running on the same machine, and what are the actual commands used). Also please confirm if you are using VPN.

Comment: Can you take a look at this [similar issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1282) in `Serving` repo? By any chance if you have any VPN enabled, Can you try disabling it and see if the issue still persists? Thanks!